# Interface a static method for Enum

Tags: java, interface, enums

`Enum.valueOf()` cannot be hidden by another static method `valueOf` of a concrete `Enum` type, but since I am creating my objects with reflection from text files I need a generic way to invoke `valueOf`.

Currently my `Enum` has a static class `fromString()`:

```
public enum Fruits {

   APPLE, ORANGE, ...;

    public static Fruit fromString(String fruit) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But how could I interface such a method that when I am dealing with an enum field type I invoke the appropriate method? The only thing I can think of is:

- using a marker interface
- implement this static method for every enum
- invoke the static method via reflection

Is there another alternative which enforces this restriction?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not using the built in .valueOf method?  Each enum class has two forms of this.  One which takes a class and name, should be called as Enum.valueOf(clazz, name).  The other belongs to the individual enum class, and should be called as Fruits.valueOf(name).  You're getting it for free, and your fromString implementation would be duplicating that functionality.

Comment: @Matt Because the Strings I am parsing are not equal to the Enum Type Name,  especially names with whitespaces in it or even special characters and I want to encapsulate the name mapping inside the enum itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'll have a number of distinct enums that you want to integrate through the unique `fromString` method. What I have done is to make a separate class that accumulates all enum members into a single `static final Map` and the `fromString` method is implemented in terms of it.

All enums implement a common interface in my case because I have a number of custom methods that I need to call irrespective of the exact enum in question.

Answer (score -2):

Sure, it's built-in: use `Enum#valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`.